# Need help to resolve library conflicts

Tags: c++

I have a .lib file created with previous versions of visual studio, perhaps 2003
I link it with my code in visual studio 2010. build succeeds but I get this warning

> warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'msvcrt.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library

I want my application to use VS2010 'msvcrt.lib' library, which is newer than the
library embedded in .lib file.

How can I make sure that the VS2010 library is linked ?
Is there any way to force my old .lib to use new 'msvcrt.lib' ?

I program in Native CPP.

Comment: You need to recompile your .lib to do this. Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944481/how-to-use-nodefaultlibs-option-in-compilation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your library might be using the older <strike>9.0</strike> 7.0 or 7.1 runtime library, as pointed out by DeadMG. In VS2010, the 10.0 runtime is the default. You might need to recompile your library with the new runtime.

**Please note that the v10 runtime targets only Windows XP SP3 or higher**. If you still wish to target lower operating systems, you will need to use the v90 runtime.

Comment: From 2003? That's a 7.0 or 7.1 runtime lib, not 9.0

Answer (score 0):

looks like the problem in Runtime Library (settings -> c/c++ -> code generation -> runtime library)

I doubt it's possible to fix it without recompiling of the 2003 lib file with DLL runtiome library (but in this case you could just compile it in 2010 studio :) )